# Can an element have box-shadow and inset shadow at the same time?

Tags: css

I want to have both and outer shadow and an inner (inset) shadow on the same element, is this possible? Right now I have this:

```
box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px #888;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #EEE;
```

with this the inset shadow overrides the normal box-shadow, any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. Separate them with a comma:

`box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px #EEE, 0 4px 2px -2px #888;`

You can have up to six I believe.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of what you want [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uttara/D2z2C/1/)

```
box-shadow:0 0 30px #222 inset, 0 4px 2px -2px #888;
```